# MalformedInputException in Tomcat using gzip on the client side?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, tomcat, soap

I'm creating a soap webservice client with `Spring` and `CXF`. The client already works, now I'm trying to enable gzip compression (because the owner of the soap webservice told me it would support HTTP compression):

```
@Autowired
private Bus bus;

bus.getInInterceptors().add(new GZIPInInterceptor());
bus.getOutInterceptors().add(new GZIPOutInterceptor());
```

This produces the following xml request:

```
Headers: {Accept=[*/*], Accept-Encoding=[gzip;q=1.0, identity; q=0.5, *;q=0], Content-Encoding=[gzip], SOAPAction=["..."]}
```

Looks fine so far. But I only get a `HTTP 500` error back. What might be wrong? Is this an error on my side, or on the webservice side?

```
XML Response:
Headers: {content-type=[text/html;charset=utf-8], Server=[Apache-Coyote/1.1], transfer-encoding=[chunked], Vary=[Accept-Encoding], X-Cnection=[close]}
HTTP Status 500 - Input length = 1
The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException

java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:277)
    sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:338)
    sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
    java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ReadConvertor.read(B2CConverter.java:252)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.B2CConverter.convert(B2CConverter.java:134)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadChars(InputBuffer.java:374)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.CharChunk.substract(CharChunk.java:379)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:388)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteReader.read(CoyoteReader.java:93)
    com.interes.hostproxy.newskies.servlets.NewskiesHostProxyServlet.doPost(NewskiesHostProxyServlet.java:275)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)

The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.41 logs.
```